# Do tags in results pages work properly?

Tags: bug, tags, search, stackexchange.com

When I run a search (as this one https://stackexchange.com/search?q=wikipedia) and then I click on a tag, I have always `Page Not Found`.

Is it ok?

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Glorfindel , it still needs to be fixed one year later :(